# Windows 7 - Open Windows Explorer, focus My Documents ("user files")

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

I want to have Windows Explorer in Windows 7 open the My Documents folder (now called "user files") by default like it did back in XP.

This first command is the closest but it goes through the C:\, so right place wrong approach...

```
%SystemRoot%\explorer.exe /n, /e, %UserProfile%
```

In example setting the shortcut to Windows Explorer in Windows 7 does the following...

Windows Explorer - Desktop

```
%SystemRoot%\explorer.exe /n,::{450D8FBA-AD25-11D0-98A8-0800361B1103}
```

Windows Explorer - My Computer

```
%SystemRoot%\explorer.exe /e,::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}
```

Comment: The command with the 450D8FBA… CLSID does exactly what you want (i.e. opens the virtual My Documents folder, not the Desktop).

Comment: If you keep calling it "My Documents", then you will get irrelevant answers. It's called "User Profile" folder, NOT "user files". http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc775560%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

Comment: @TFM The actual "Documents" folder in the user profile folder (by default) is still "My Documents" (even on Windows 8).

Comment: @techie007: The `%SystemRoot%\explorer.exe /n, /e, %UserProfile%` leads to the "User Profile" folder, and according to the OP that it works correctly (but the approach is not correct?). So to my understanding, he's not looking for the "My Documents", as in `%UserProfile%\My Documents`. And there's no such thing as a "User Files" folder, right?

Comment: @TFM Yeah it's hard to guess what the user wants.  Oh well he's got info on how to get to the User Profile folder AND My Documents, amongst others, so hey, the answer is here some place. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows 7 Documents:

```
explorer shell:DocumentsLibrary
```

Windows 7 Desktop:

```
explorer shell:Desktop
```

Windows 7 My Computer:

```
explorer shell:MyComputerFolder
```

[image: explorer shell commands]

Answer (score 1):

I use this:

```
%windir%\explorer.exe /n /e,::{59031a47-3f72-44a7-89c5-5595fe6b30ee}
```

It opens the users profile folder and the hierarchy tree in the side-panel shows the folder under `Desktop` and not `Desktop>Computer>Local Disk (C:)>\Users\username` which I think is what OP meant by 'but it goes through the C:\, so right place wrong approach...'

Answer (score 0):

If your actual "My Documents" folder is still located within your User Profile, then you were close:

`%SystemRoot%\explorer.exe /n, /e, "%UserProfile%/My Documents"`

will open Explorer in your "My Documents" folder, assuming you haven't moved it out of your user's profile folder.